# Exterior derivative of a representation

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, representation-theory

If for example, we have a representation $ρ(g)$ ($g$ an element of the group $G$) which acts on, say, X i.e. ρ(g)X
How can we define the exterior derivative of the representation i.e. dρ(g)? How does it act?

Comment: What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: I guess $G$ is a Lie group and $X$ a manifold?